# Integration over a shifted circle $\iint_D \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} d y\, d x$ where $D$ is a shifted parametrised disc.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, multiple-integral

Consider the disc $D$ is centred at $(\bar{r},0)$ with radius $c$.

Illustration of $D$ :

[image]

The inner integration can be easily dealt with by using polar coordinate. However the difficulty is the outermost integration. This is how far I got to:

Converting the integral into polar coordinate we get:

$$\int_{-\alpha}^{\alpha}\int_{\bar{r}\cos(\theta)-\sqrt{-\bar{r}\sin^2(\theta)+ c^2} }^{\bar{r}\cos(\theta)+\sqrt{-\bar{r}\sin^2(\theta)+ c^2} } \frac{1}{r} r\, d r \,d \theta \\
= \int_{-\alpha}^{\alpha}2\sqrt{-\bar{r}\sin^2(\theta)+ c^2}\,d\theta
$$

Now the problem is how to integrate and define the bounds $\alpha$ in terms of $\bar{r}$ and $c$. It seems there should be a clever substitution trick.

The final result should be something like $$2 \pi\left({\bar{r}}-\sqrt{\bar{r}^2-c^2}\right)$$

[ref.  Mechanics of Materials 9th Edition c2014 - Hibbeler, Table 6-1]

Comment: That final result is definitely wrong. Plugging in $c=\bar{r}$ suggests the answer should be $2\pi \bar{r}$, but actually doing the integral gives $$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^{2\bar{r}\cos\theta}dr\:d\theta = 4\bar{r}$$